# Is there any library/component for dial-up connections?

Tags: connection, components, modem, dial-up

I want to dial-up through VoIP. Yes, I know that it's almost impossible. I have heard that softmodems use software for DSP, but I guess the code its hardware specific. If I only could isolate the code that makes the modem signal I could use it on my project. Anyone ever heard about a library that would fullfill my needs?

PS: iaxmodem only modulates fax signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but take a look at the Dialogic [SDK](http://www.dialogic.com/products/tdm_boards/development_tools/Diva_Server_Software_Development_Kit.htm) and it's [API manuals](http://www.dialogic.com/support/helpweb/dssdk/).

I've been doing some work on a Dialogic voice/fax board, and on one of the machines that I'm using I've set up the SDK but without having a board installed (they're pretty expensive).

I've noticed that on this machine, since I don't have the board installed, it's provided me with a softIP virtual-hardware board, managed by their software.

I haven't played with the VoIP stuff myself, but it might provide some of what you need.

Here's a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/2GHfw.jpg).

Downloading and installing the SDK is free, though when you enter your details they will probably give you a call and try to sell you a board.

Answer (score 0):

Most telephone audio codecs compress the data using [perceptual coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychoacoustics). This coding can **not** reproduce all frequencies of the source at the target, as it omits the ones that are *irrelevant*. Therfore you can **not** use a data encoding that encodes binary data into audio frequencies (like a modem does) with GSM or VoIP.

Besides that: having VoIP means having an [IP connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol), so why not transfer the data via IP (if it needs to be secure via a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) instead of trying to use a modem over VoIP?

Comment: but codecs like G711 transmit the full PCM signal (64kbps) enabling some modem connections. I know that the connection will be unstable because of the discretization noise, lost packets and the jitter, but it is possible.